# PyCharm Python logging vs prompter flush race?

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, flush

Consider this simple example:

```
import logging
from prompter import prompt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.info("when do you think I am going to be printed?")
    input_ = prompt("Type in your input: ")
    print input_
```

If I run the script from command the output seems to be consistently correct:

```
python logger_vs_prompter.py
when do you think I am going to be printed?
Type in your input:  A
A
```

Now if I run it through PyCharm IDE, no matter if "run" or "debug", the output gets unpredictable:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.6817.19)
Type in your input:  when do you think I am going to be printed?
A
A

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.6817.19)
when do you think I am going to be printed?
Type in your input:  A
A

C:\devel\Python-2.7\python.exe logger_vs_prompter.py
Type in your input:  when do you think I am going to be printed?
D
D
```

I even tried to force logger flush by adding

```
logger.handlers[0].flush()
```

But no help.

I tend to suspect that this is an IDE issue and that I should not bother about having clumsy output in my real use case but, is there a way to ensure the output order, nevertheless?